# Built-in dictionary usage on Adobe Acrobat DC

Tags: macos, pdf, dictionary, adobe

I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 2019 on my mac. I get used to use built-in dictionary of mac via three-fingers clicking on a word. However, it works on other applications like chrome, pdfguru etc. but not on Acrobat Pro DC. Even <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> doesn't work. How can I use the dictionary on it?

Comment: see https://medium.com/@hlung/how-to-quickly-look-up-a-word-in-dictionary-mac-os-x-ef500d6cbdd

Comment: @DaniilManokhin nope, it doesn't work

Comment: I don't think Adobe uses the macOS Dictionary. Right click a word and select "Look up ___." On my system it opens a web browser with the definition of the selected word.

Comment: @SteveChambers yes, same case is applied to yet the fact that I'm not native speaker necessitate to glance at synonyms of the current word. The act genuinely is helpful.

Comment: This still dosen't work in May 2020. Does anyone know what the problem is? Should one blame Adobe or Apple?

Answer (score 2):

I come up with a solution by using bettertouchtool but it nearly meets my wish. It opens the dictionary application instead of popping-up.

Download and install Better Touch Tool.

[Add Adobe Reader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDgwW.jpg)

Then select "Keyboard" tab (between "Trackpads" and "Apple remote")

Select "Adobe Reader" at the left sidebar.

Click "Add New Shortcut" and select preferable shortcut (in my case: Command + D).

Then select action: "Controlling Other Application" -> "Send Shortcut to Specific App", select "Adobe Reader" and press "Command + C".

Select newly created shortcut and click "Attach Additional Action" and attach action: "Controlling Other Application" -> "Execute Terminal Command" and paste

```
open dict://`pbpaste`
```

Comment: Can you add force touch (like the usual method for looking up a word in the dictionary) instead of Cmd + D?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **Bettertouchtool** workflow

```
    [
  {
    "BTTTriggerType" : 203,
    "BTTTriggerTypeDescription" : "Single Finger FORCE Click",
    "BTTTriggerClass" : "BTTTriggerTypeTouchpadAll",
    "BTTPredefinedActionType" : 54,
    "BTTPredefinedActionName" : "Double Click",
    "BTTEnabled2" : 1,
    "BTTAlternateModifierKeys" : 0,
    "BTTRepeatDelay" : 0,
    "BTTUUID" : "A453AD8A-26F9-4A52-831F-BEE6AED7EB72",
    "BTTNotesInsteadOfDescription" : 0,
    "BTTEnabled" : 1,
    "BTTModifierMode" : 0,
    "BTTOrder" : 0,
    "BTTDisplayOrder" : 0,
    "BTTAdditionalActions" : [
      {
        "BTTTriggerType" : -1,
        "BTTTriggerClass" : "BTTTriggerTypeTouchpadAll",
        "BTTPredefinedActionType" : -1,
        "BTTPredefinedActionName" : "No Action",
        "BTTLayoutIndependentActionChar" : "c",
        "BTTAutoAdaptActionToKeyboardLayout" : true,
        "BTTShortcutToSend" : "55,8",
        "BTTEnabled2" : 1,
        "BTTAlternateModifierKeys" : 0,
        "BTTRepeatDelay" : 0,
        "BTTUUID" : "B2806FF7-BEC1-4D25-8E50-3FD0C524D0E3",
        "BTTNotesInsteadOfDescription" : 0,
        "BTTEnabled" : 1,
        "BTTModifierMode" : 0,
        "BTTOrder" : 1,
        "BTTDisplayOrder" : 0
      },
      {
        "BTTTriggerType" : -1,
        "BTTTriggerClass" : "BTTTriggerTypeTouchpadAll",
        "BTTPredefinedActionType" : 137,
        "BTTPredefinedActionName" : "Execute Terminal Command (Async, non-blocking)",
        "BTTTerminalCommand" : "open dict:\/\/`pbpaste`",
        "BTTEnabled2" : 1,
        "BTTAlternateModifierKeys" : 0,
        "BTTRepeatDelay" : 0,
        "BTTUUID" : "77076437-D1C5-4A7C-9142-773DEF3EF42C",
        "BTTNotesInsteadOfDescription" : 0,
        "BTTEnabled" : 1,
        "BTTModifierMode" : 0,
        "BTTOrder" : 2,
        "BTTDisplayOrder" : 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "BTTTriggerType" : -1,
    "BTTTriggerClass" : "BTTTriggerTypeTouchpadAll",
    "BTTPredefinedActionType" : -1,
    "BTTPredefinedActionName" : "No Action",
    "BTTLayoutIndependentActionChar" : "c",
    "BTTAutoAdaptActionToKeyboardLayout" : true,
    "BTTShortcutToSend" : "55,8",
    "BTTEnabled2" : 1,
    "BTTAlternateModifierKeys" : 0,
    "BTTRepeatDelay" : 0,
    "BTTUUID" : "B2806FF7-BEC1-4D25-8E50-3FD0C524D0E3",
    "BTTNotesInsteadOfDescription" : 0,
    "BTTEnabled" : 1,
    "BTTModifierMode" : 0,
    "BTTOrder" : 1,
    "BTTDisplayOrder" : 0
  },
  {
    "BTTTriggerType" : -1,
    "BTTTriggerClass" : "BTTTriggerTypeTouchpadAll",
    "BTTPredefinedActionType" : 137,
    "BTTPredefinedActionName" : "Execute Terminal Command (Async, non-blocking)",
    "BTTTerminalCommand" : "open dict:\/\/`pbpaste`",
    "BTTEnabled2" : 1,
    "BTTAlternateModifierKeys" : 0,
    "BTTRepeatDelay" : 0,
    "BTTUUID" : "77076437-D1C5-4A7C-9142-773DEF3EF42C",
    "BTTNotesInsteadOfDescription" : 0,
    "BTTEnabled" : 1,
    "BTTModifierMode" : 0,
    "BTTOrder" : 2,
    "BTTDisplayOrder" : 0
  }
]
```

Comment: This should be an edit to https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/349240/237 as it is providing more details for that answer